# Codeigniter delete link does not appear in my view table

Tags: php, codeigniter

Could you check why the row cannot be deleted. I get database error: Deletes are not allowed unless they contain a "where" or "like" clause. Your help is highly appreciated

Here is my view:

```
                    <td><a href="<?php echo base_url("admin/delete_row/".$user['user_id']
                     ); ?>">Delete</a></td>
```

Here is my controller:

```
public function delete_row() {

    if ($this->session->userdata('is_admin_logged_in')){

        $this->load->model("model_admin");
        $this->model_admin->did_delete_row();

        }
        else
        {
            redirect('admin/login'); 
        }

    }
```

Here is my Model:

```
public function did_delete_row(){ 

    $this->db->where('user_id', $this->input->get('user_id'));
    $this->db->delete('users'); 

    if ($this->db->delete('users')) 

        {return true;}

        else

        {return false;}

                }
```

Comment: your link is not getting shown or not working?

Comment: not getting shown but when I delete this part of code <?php echo $user['user_id'];?> it is getting shown

Comment: try replacing base_url() with the complete path, perhaps, you forgot to load url helpers

Comment: url helper is loaded, the problem is with this part of code <?php echo $user['user_id'];?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**try this :**

```
<td><a href="<?php echo base_url("admin/delete_row/".$user['user_id']); ?>">Delete</a></td>
```

check your **[URL Helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)** is loaded . and value of `$user['user_id']` is set

if data in `object` format then simply replace `$user['user_id']` with `$user->user_id`

```
<td><a href="<?php echo base_url("admin/delete_row/".$user->user_id); ?>">Delete</a></td>
```

**controller:**

```
public function delete_row(){
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3)
    if ($this->session->userdata('is_admin_logged_in'))
    {
        $this->load->model("model_admin");
        $this->model_admin->did_delete_row($id);
    }
    else
    {
        redirect('admin/login'); 
    }

}
```

**Model:**

```
public function did_delete_row($id){ 

    if ($this->db->delete('users', array('user_id' => $id))) 
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: URL helper is loaded. I tried in the way you described but it still does not show the link

Comment: check value of $user['user_id'] is set ??

Comment: I have just added my view code. Could you check if  $user['user_id'] is set?

Comment: @TProDeveloper replace $user['user_id'] with $user->user_id.

Comment: I did it. Now link appears but when I click on the link it shows error "Deletes are not allowed unless they contain a "where" or "like" clause.". Could you help me please.

Comment: I have just added my controller and model codes. Could you please check them.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50847/discussion-between-haseeb-and-tprodeveloper)

Comment: Hi Haseeb, Hope you are doing well:) Could you please check my question. Maybe you can help me to find the mistake. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23911438/codeigniter-get-data-from-database-using-ajax-in-codeigniter

Comment: @TProDeveloper join this chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54693/codeigniter-issue

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
 <td>
   <a href=<?php echo base_url()."admin/delete_row/".$user['user_id'];?>>Delete</a>
</td>
```