# Get a single row from the database using AJAX in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, codeigniter

I wonder how to get data from database using AJAX in CodeIgniter. Could you please check the code below to find out the reason of problem? Nothing happens when I click on the link from my view.

Here is my view:

```
<a href="#" class="faq_title"><?php echo $faq_title; ?></a>
```

Here is my controller:

```
public function get_faq_data() {
    $this->load->model("model_faq");
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $data["results"] = $this->model_faq->did_get_faq_data($title);
    echo json_encode($data["results"]);
}
```

Here is my model:

```
public function did_get_faq_data($title) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('faq');   
    $this->db->where('faq_title', $title); 

    $query = $this->db->get('faq');

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is my JavaScript file:

```
$(".faq_title").click(function() {
    var title = $(this).text();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'faq/get_faq_data',
        data: ({ title: title }),
        dataType: 'json', 
        type: 'post',
        success: function(data) {
            response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            console.log(response);
        }             
    });
});
```

Comment: Look into `json_encode()` if you want your AJAX call to easily parse and use the data. Check **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20150130/ajax-and-php-to-enter-multiple-forms-input-to-database/20150474#20150474)** out for more ideas

Comment: I'd also suggest using a json view and return rather thant 'echo' in your controller. I think CI passes some headers which may cause issues with json.

Comment: @David a JSON view is definitely the proper way to do this especially if you set `compression = true` in the config otherwise your app will bomb-out. I have personally never seen a headers issue when simply echoing it especially if you tell the AJAX call to expect a JSON return string but then again, never say never =)

Comment: Could you check now please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function(){ // start of doc ready.
   $(".faq_title").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();  // stops the jump when an anchor clicked.
      var title = $(this).text(); // anchors do have text not values.

      $.ajax({
        url: 'faq/get_faq_data',
        data: {'title': title}, // change this to send js object
        type: "post",
        success: function(data){
           //document.write(data); just do not use document.write
           console.log(data);
        }
      });
   });
}); // end of doc ready
```

---

The issue as i see is this `var title = $(this).val();` as your selector `$(".faq_title")` is an anchor and anchors have text not values. So i suggested you to use `.text()` instead of `.val()`.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have just edited my code but still nothing happens while clicking on the link. Could you check my code once more?

Comment: ok thank you, now I should learn how to pass js object instead of variable

Comment: Could you check now please?

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, you aren't using the anchor tag for its intended purpose, so perhaps just use a `<p>` tag or something.  Ideally, you should use an `id` integer instead of a `title` to identify a row in your database.

View:

```
<p class="faq_title"><?php echo $faq_title; ?></p>
```

If you had an `id` integer, you could use a `$_GET` request an receive the `id` as the lone parameter of the `get_faq_data()` method.

Controller:

```
public function faqByTitle(): void
{
    if (!$this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
        show_404();
    }
    $title = $this->input->post('title');
    if ($title === null) {
        show_404();
    }
    $this->load->model('model_faq', 'FAQModel');
    echo json_encode($this->FAQModel->getOne($title));
}
```

FAQ Model:

```
public function getOne(string $title): ?object
{
    return $this->db->get_where('faq', ['faq_title' => $title])->row(); 
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".faq_title").click(function() {
    let title = $(this).text();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'faq/faqByTitle',
        data: {title:title},
        dataType: 'json', 
        type: 'post',
        success: function(response) {
           console.log(response);
        }             
    });
});
```

None of these snippets have been tested.